# Cycling through an array in JavaScript using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cycle

I come from a Ruby background, so forgive me if this is an amateurish question. I have a color selector, where a paragraph changes its text to match a color

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Please Select a Color</button>
<p class="color-select"></p>
```

JavaScript/Jquery

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".color-select").html(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]);
  });
});
```

As you can see, I am well aware of how to select a random element in JavaScript. In Ruby, it would be even simpler

```
colors.sample
```

But what I would like to do is to cycle through the colors. If I click on the button, the text will read `red`. If I click on it again, the text will read `green`. After the text is `purple`, it will cycle back to `red` and keep cycling through the various colors.

One insane, wacky idea I have is something like the following.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < colors.length) {
  $('.color-select').html(colors[i]);
  i++;
  if (i == 4) {
    i = 0
  }
}
```

That will probably not work because the text is changing without clicking a button. Any ideas?

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c7ea2m6f/

Answer (score 7):

This will work for you.

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".color-select").html(colors[i]);
        i++;
        i = i % 5;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c7ea2m6f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c7ea2m6f/4/

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "purple"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
  $("button").click(function() {
      if (i < colors.length) {
    $(".color-select").html(colors[i]);
     i++;
          if (i == 5) {
              i = 0;
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Use an `if` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Edit: You mentioned red twice in your colors array. To avoid confusion, I changed it to something different.